# Parse-Sinch integration unable to send messages to users created using Parse's data browser

Tags: android, parse-platform, sinch

I am trying to integrate Parse with Sinch using the source code in [Github](https://github.com/sinch/android-messaging-tutorial). Everything works fine as long as the user is signed up using the Android API ParseUser.signUpInBackground(). However when I create a Parse user using Parse's website, I am unable to send messages to the newly created user. I am getting an error "User does not exist". This happens too if the user has signed up using Facebook and Twitter. I also observed that when you do a login to the newly created user then the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because sinch doesnt know about that user yet, you need to login in an app and start the client once so sinch know where to send messages and incoming call notifications.

Comment: I see. Is there a way for the application to tell Sinch about the user when the Sinch API detects that it hasn't been created?

Comment: Hi, not really, you cant be certain the user even installed the app. You should probably only display that you can send messages to users that have installed the app and started the sinch client once.